# MySQL FK error 1822

Tags: mysql, foranea

he creado una tabla simple de prueba donde cree varias claves foráneas, pero hay una que me dice que no puedo crearla por un "missed index", he buscado en todas las respuestas, intentado borrar las tablas y crear la que referencio antes de la otra y demás, pero sigue saliendo el mismo error. Les dejo mi código para que vean... Realmente no entiendo cual es mi error. Muchas gracias  a todos, que tengan un lindo día.
ahh!! Estoy trabajando en workbench. Gracias!!

```
create table Mascotas (
ID int not null,
Nombre varchar(20),
Id_Dueño int not null,
Servicio varchar(150)
);

create table Personas (
ID int not null,
Nombre varchar(20),
Apellido varchar (25),
COD_ZIP varchar(10),
TLF int not null
);

create table Direcciones (
ZIP varchar(10),
Nombre_zona varchar(30),
Ruta varchar(30)
);


alter table Mascotas
add primary key(ID);
alter table Personas
add primary key(ID);

alter table Mascotas
add constraint dueño
foreign key(Id_Dueño) references Personas(ID);

alter table Personas
add constraint zip
foreign key(COD_ZIP) references prueba.Direcciones(ZIP);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y donde dices que ZIP es algo en la tabla direcciones????

Comment: Intenta quitando en la última línea la palabra **prueba.** y deja solo **Direcciones(ZIP)**. Adicionalmente no has creado el primary key en la tabla Direcciones. Ten cuidado, una clave primaria debe ser un campo único y auto incrementable.